# Finding same memory address again

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, ram

I'm trying to create a HUD system to a game by reading the values from RAM.

I have succeeded at getting the values from RAM but after I close the program and start it again, the address has changed.

How can I find the addresses again automatically?

For example current health was found at: 0A0B50C0 but after restart, that address was empty.

Comment: By "HUD system" you mean a hack for a game? Not sure if it's legal.

Comment: I don't think so. This game is 15 years old. Playing it for fun but the UI is way too old for me to enjoy the game completely.

Plus this is perfect way to practice. :)